# Portfolio problem on a flash template

Tags: flash, templates, button, portfolio

I have another question about the same template as before.

in my website. (www.nikstudio.cl) I need to show in the webpage's portfolio (menu "trabajos") show a few pictures. If you click the thumbnail picture you can see the full size version of that thumbnail. My problem are two:

First the picture one and two are the same as five a six ( and i can't change it cause i don't find the place to do this.)

And the second is when I copy and paste (in a new layer) of the movieclip "sprite 656" i get in the swf a new picture on the portfolio but i can't click it.

Can you help me why is that???

pd: the full template is here. (the .fla an all the files) http://hotfile.com/dl/93339597/35e8fdb/new_28781.zip.zip.html

thanks

Comment: Hey mate. The link you provided is another template. If you could upload the new FLA (only the FLA) I could take a look at your stuff.

Comment: damn i'm so dumb. here it is
http://hotfile.com/dl/93339597/35e8fdb/new_28781.zip.zip.html

Comment: just the .fla http://hotfile.com/dl/94002495/ad2a456/mio24.fla.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the images:

1. Go to Layer 174 / Frame 2, Select the 'pages_mov' movie clip for editing (double

click)
2. Go to Layer 971 / Frame 12, Select the 'page_all' movie clip for editing (double

click)
3. Go to Layer 12 / Frame 4, Select the 'pages_anim' movie clip for editing (double

click)
4. Go to Layer 1 / Frame 1, select the 'pages' movie clip for editing (double click)
5. Go to Layer 45/ Frame 1, select the 'item1' movie clip for editing (double click)
6. Go to Layer 4 / Frame 1, select the 'pic' movie clip for editing (double click)
7. The images are placed on Layer 1

Adding / Removing images:

1. Select the 'pages' movieclip for editing (double click) (go there by following 1-4 steps)
2. Select the second frame on the Action Layer, open the code editor (Window/Actions)
3. `num_pic = 7;` This variable stores how many images you have on the stage, so if you want to add or remove, amed this value accordingly.
4. If you want to add a new image, make sure you change its instance name. it is now item1, item2... item5
5. Every image instance has a method which is called when the onLoad event is triggered (The instance is loaded):

   onClipEvent (load)
       {
           num1 = 4;
           num = 4;
           this.hitArea = this.area;
       }

Here you have to edit the numbers according to the instance name of the image.

I hope it helps,
Rob